# how to emit a file through socket.io

Tags: socket.io

how can i send a file path through socket.io i.e

genrally we use

```
socket.emit("sendpath","hi" );
socket.on("sendpath",function()
{
console.log("hi")
}
```

to emit a file path i.e a pdf file which is in my c drive how can that happen

path is :-"C:\xampp\248.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand your question, but I'm going to assume that you want the contents of a file, given the path to that file, provided as a Socket.IO event.

```
// var fs = require("fs");
socket.on("sendpath",filepath){
    fs.readFile(filepath,function(error, filedata){
        if(error) throw error;
        else socket.emit("sendfile", filedata.toString() );
    });
});
```

Reference: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback

Comment: Hey ..... isnt it better if i do :-

socket.emit("sendfile", Path : "c://file//")

Comment: First of all, could you please confirm that my interpretation of your question is correct? Now, assuming it is, you can not write `Path : "c://file//"` ... invalid syntax.

Comment: Could you please provide links where I can learn more about this? It does seem to work, but I don't understand it yet.