# Send file to client witouth response function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to send a html file to the client after a io.on event listner.
i first use the normal

```
    `app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")

})`
```

to send the file. But then i want to send a new file to the client after a socket.on:

```
    io.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("password" function(){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "loggedin.html");
})
 })
```

how would i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817173/how-to-emit-a-file-through-socket-io

Comment: well kind of, i want it to be automaticly displayed as a page tho. This link only talks about how to send the file not actually displaying it

Answer (score 0):

You can emit an event from the server to inform the client to load the page:

```
// In the server
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  socket.on("password", function () {
    // ...Any other logic that needs to be here...
    // Emit an event to inform the client load the page
    socket.emit('load_index_page');
  })
})
```

..

```
// Somewhere in the client
socket.on('load_index_page', function () {
  window.location.assign("/index.html")
})
```